# how to make text or richtext scrollable in flutter?

Tags: flutter

It seems text/richtext only support one page, if the content exceed the screen, you can't scroll up/down. Is there an easy way to enable it? 
Or I have to use the Scrolling Widgets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flutter provide a lot of Scrolling Widgets [documentation](https://flutter.io/widgets/scrolling/)

Example :[SingleChildScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

[image]

```
class mytext extends StatelessWidget {
var randomtext="....";
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Container(child: new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(),
  body: new SingleChildScrollView(child: 
    new Text(randomtext,style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),),),
),);
 }
}
```

Comment: Great,  Thank you!